# Need to Debug VBA code for Clearing Contents of a Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a simple macro to clear the contents of column A. My spreadsheet has three sheets called "Input Screen", "Proposal Database", and "Rankings". When I am in the "Proposal database" screen the macro works fine. Howveer, the macro does nto work when it is run from other screens (even though there is nor error with the code). Why is this? Any help will eb much appreciated! The code is as follows:

```
Sub Clear_Contents_Column_A()

With Worksheets("Proposal Database")

Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

End With

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Ollie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.` before `Range`. It will specify that `Range` belongs to certain `Worksheet`:

```
Sub Clear_Contents_Column_A()

   With Worksheets("Proposal Database")
      .Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
   End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question can be read in different ways.  I suspect that @simoco has provided the answer you are looking for, but if you are asking how to use the macro to clear column A in your other worksheets, then you need to change the worksheet name in your macro. You're instructing the macro to run on Sheet ("Proposal Database").  Unless you change the name of the sheet it won't run on other worksheets.  You could change

```
  With Worksheets("Proposal Database")
```

to

```
  With ActiveSheet
```

if you want the macro to run from any worksheet in the workbook.